# Reformatting drive from a GUID partition to an MBR partition

Tags: encryption, windows, truecrypt, bitlocker

I understand that Truecrypt is not compatible with an GUID partition but that is the limit of my knowledge.

I am currently using a system that has a GUID partition but doesn't have bitlocker available.

Was just wondering if one is able to perform a fresh install on windows, whilst formatting the drive to an MBR partition, and still keep all old files and data kept outside the windows folder?

Would I have to back up all files to an external hard drive whilst I perform the switch-over?

Anybody got any advice as to how I'd perform this operation, as to be totally honest I am an utter novice.

Comment: This question would be better asked on superuser... but in short, you need to back up your data, as any *format* results in a total loss of all data in the partition, and changing from GUID to MBR (or any other combination) will destroy *all* partitions on the drive. Make sure you back up everything, even recovery partitions, or you may never be able to recover your system.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I may also ask on superuser to ensure I understand the implications of what I'm doing properly. (Certainly don't want to end up losing all my data)

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26203-convert-gpt-disk-mbr-disk.html might help